# My class flex wrap is not apply to div item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

I have little issue with Flex wrap, my code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">

                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div id="mr">
                                <div class="item " id="1">1</div>
                                <div class="item " id="2">2</div>
                                <div class="item " id="3">3</div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

And CSS

```
.item {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem .5rem;
    background: #53d5bb;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#mr {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.box {
    height: 400px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can this be up to Bulma CSS or I miss something? Why this class  ***flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;*** doesn't work? Also, here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kv3gfs4r/1/

Answer (score 1):

It works. When you resizes the window and container is not fully visible it works as it should. I would say it starts from bottom and wrap to the top so when wrap is needed it just writes from the bottom to top.

there is of course `flex-direction: row-reverse` that that would reverse the order of every element.

Please refer to what do you want to accomplish.